# How can I set a default pseudo styles in my css?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I wanted to start minifying the css I have to write and figured this would save a bunch of lines in the long run.

I want to set a global(default) style for `:before` and `:after` so I don't have to keep repeating styles like `content: "";` over and over throughout my css.

I then decided to give it a try in a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u43dw/1) and had some odd behaviors.

**Edit**

How can I apply certain styles, like `content: "";` only to elements I assign a pseudo element to? The sample code in the fiddle applies a pseudo element to any element in the DOM not just elements I assign a pseudo element to.

Lets say I have the following code:

```
<div></div>
```

and

```
<div class="sideTri"></div>
```

with the following css:

```
:before {
    content: "";
}

.sideTri:before {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid brown;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
}
```

This will assign a pseudo `:before` to both of the elements and not just the class I am assigning a pseudo element to.

**End Edit**

Comment: You gonna have a lot of trouble doing this. It will possibly create a lot of useless elements.

Comment: The question is obscure. It sounds like “can I set things global without making them global”.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I want to set a global style only for pseudo elements not every tag. Only when I need to use a pseudo element so I don't have to keep writing the same style over and over.

Comment: You should clarify your problem by editing or rewriting the question, using generally known HTML and CSS terms. E.g., “only for pseudo elements” is obscure, since the sample code does just that, and it apparently isn’t what you want.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I edited my question but I do want it to target any and every pseudo element that is attached to an element not every element. The sample code in the fiddle targets any element on the DOM and applies a `:before` to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, these pseudo-elements are being applied to `html`, `head`, `body` and *all* of their descendants (at least, where applicable according to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content)). The two that you see belong to `html` and `body` respectively. (You don't see the ones generated by `head` or its descendants because they're hidden by default, but they are there.)

You can [restrict this with a `body` selector](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/u43dw/2):

```
body :before {
    content: "";
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: black;
    display: block;
}
```

But I strongly advise against applying `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements universally like this, if nothing else because it creates unnecessary overhead — every element now has to draw an additional pseudo-element box.

There is virtually no sensible use case for having every element generate a pseudo-element. It's usually a much better idea to limit which elements to apply them to rather than to just have them apply on everything; that way you exercise the greatest control over them.

Comment: Hmm I was really hoping it wouldn't apply it to every element. The `body :before` is nice but everything doesn't need a `:before` on it. Is there anyway I can go about this to apply `content: "";` to every pseudo element that I use without everything getting it?

Comment: @JoshPowell yup, you can do just that, a pseudo element without a `content` rule will not be created. So remove the `content` rule from the global `:before` and add it to the specific `:before`s you want to use.

Comment: @Josh Powell: Not really, because it's precisely `content: ""` (or any other value than `none`) that makes an element generate a pseudo-element. You could have `body :before { content: ""; }` and your styles in separate specific rules, but then you would still be causing every element to draw an extra box (albeit an empty one that doesn't occupy space). You could have `body :before { content: ""; display: none; }` to prevent that but you would have to add `display: block` to elements that you do want to have pseudo-elements.

Comment: @BoltClock oh I see. If `content` was always empty though, wouldn't setting it on the elements you want to use be as repetitive as setting `display: block`?

Comment: @myajouri: Yeah that's true. I don't think we can win in this case.

Comment: Well that is upsetting but oh well, thanks for all of the help!